# Почему не работает event.preventDefault() если определить пространство имен для события?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Так работает (в этом случае переход по ссылке не осуществится):

```
$(document).off('click').on('click','a.button',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('click')
});
```

А так не работает (в этом случае мы перейдем по ссылке):

```
$(document).off('click.myNameSpace').on('click.myNameSpace','a.button',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('click')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё работает:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.no', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('click')
});

$(document).on('click.myNameSpace', 'a.yes', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('click')
});
```

```css
a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="no" href="data:text/plain,Navigated">Without namespace</a>
<a class="yes" href="data:text/plain,Navigated">With namespace</a>
<a href="data:text/plain,Navigated">Unhandled</a>
```

Comment: Перепроверьте указанный автором вариант с `.off`. У меня для вашего примера с добавленным методом `.off()` срабатывает навигация для ссылки `.no`. Последняя Opera, если что

Comment: @VenZell, а ты в курсе, что через `.off('click')` отписываешься от всех кликов, в том числе с неймспейсом?

Comment: @VenZell, <s>добавь сниппет с неработающим кодом в вопрос.</s> Ой.. Вопрос не твой... Тогда ссылку на jsfidle в комментарий :)

Comment: да, я в курсе поведения метода `.off()`. Однако автор так может сбрасывать навешенные ранее клики, чтобы повесить новый обработчик. И это не объясняет описанного мной поведения. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/venzell/tm3g4o1v/ . Или я ошибаюсь? В любом случае, пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ и в том, и другом случае.

Comment: Возможно, у меня сложилось ложное впечатление, что вы не заметили вызов этого метода у автора вопроса

Comment: @VenZell, в фиддле ты перед второй подпиской делаешь `.off('click')`, чем отписываешься от первой. Поэтому с неймспейсом подписчик есть (он добавлен позже), а без неймспейса - нет. Поменяешь местами куски скрипта - и будет наоборот. А если вместо этого изменишь вторую отписку на `.off('click.myNameSpace')` - будет всё хорошо.

Comment: Епрст, и правда. На ночь глядя котелок уже не варит. В рамках строчки только проанализировал действие... Примите мои извинения тогда

Comment: Странно, почему у меня не работает, может из-за того что у меня jQuery v1.11.3? хотя это врядли

Comment: @sanu0074, сниппет в вопрос добавь. Или на jsfiddle.